# MATLAB: Printing a formatted table

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

I'm working on an iteration program on MATLAB (Jacobi iteration method on solving A **x** = **b** ), which allows me to make N iterations.

So far, I can code the iteration, but I want to improve the presentation of the results.

My program's output:

```
jacobi(A, b, 20);  %N = 20 iterations
```

Values of `x` by columns of iteration(s) (starting at 0) from left to right:

```
X =
```

Columns 1 through 9

```
     0    3.4000   -0.0556    1.3848    1.0250    0.9300    1.0558    0.9813    1.0034
     0    4.0000    0.8603    2.1810    2.0329    1.9030    2.0453    1.9826    1.9997
     0    2.5000    4.5444    2.1023    3.3195    2.9782    2.9513    3.0402    2.9831
     0    2.0000    5.3463    3.5175    4.0772    4.0612    3.9463    4.0266    3.9939
     0    6.7778    3.8111    5.4106    4.9648    4.9366    5.0513    4.9777    5.0046
```

Columns 10 through 18

```
1.0026    0.9979    1.0011    0.9998    1.0000    1.0001    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
2.0027    1.9977    2.0008    1.9998    1.9999    2.0001    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000
3.0035    3.0013    2.9984    3.0009    2.9998    3.0000    3.0001    3.0000    3.0000
3.9990    4.0022    3.9988    4.0004    4.0000    3.9999    4.0001    4.0000    4.0000
5.0015    4.9979    5.0011    4.9997    5.0000    5.0001    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
```

Columns 19 through 21

```
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
2.0000    2.0000    2.0000
3.0000    3.0000    3.0000
4.0000    4.0000    4.0000
5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
```

Nevermind if you guys never heard of such method, but I'm wondering, if I were to insert strings such that it becomes

```
jacobi(A, b, 20);
```

Values of x by columns of iteration(s) (starting at 0) from left to right:

X =

Columns 1 through 9

```
   iteration
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0  |    1   |    2    |    3    |    4    |    5    |    6    |    7    |     8
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0    3.4000   -0.0556    1.3848    1.0250    0.9300    1.0558    0.9813    1.0034
      0    4.0000    0.8603    2.1810    2.0329    1.9030    2.0453    1.9826    1.9997
      0    2.5000    4.5444    2.1023    3.3195    2.9782    2.9513    3.0402    2.9831
      0    2.0000    5.3463    3.5175    4.0772    4.0612    3.9463    4.0266    3.9939
      0    6.7778    3.8111    5.4106    4.9648    4.9366    5.0513    4.9777    5.0046
```

and so on, how exactly do I do that?

I'm thinking of inserting `------ up`, `i  |` middle, and `------` below and number of iterations in the loop to let it generate as many as N desired.

So far, the closest example I've found on searches, is

```
arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('Hole %j',x), 1:18)','UniformOutput',false)
```

But still, I can't figure out how to incorporate this idea into my code. Is this kind of output possible in MATLAB?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

I'm taking a course on MATLAB, but with just a couple of months of lessons, there's not much stuffs I have learned yet. But I'm looking for a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to add strings to the matrix itself.

It's all a matter of **formatting** the result when **displaying** it. For instance, you can go about the following solution that employs [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) and some string formatting (no loops!):

```
% # Initialize table properties
col_w = 11;  % # Fixed column width in characters
fr_n = 4;    % # Number of fraction digits

% # Print header
hdr_line = repmat(['+', char('-' * ones(1, col_w))], 1, size(X, 2));
hdr_fmt = ['|%', int2str(col_w - fr_n - 1)', '.0f', char(' ' * ones(1, fr_n + 1))];
fprintf('Iteration:\n%s\n', hdr_line)
fprintf(hdr_fmt, 0:size(X, 2) - 1)
fprintf('\n%s\n', hdr_line)

% # Print values
data_fmt = [repmat(['|%', int2str(col_w - 1), '.', int2str(fr_n), 'f '], 1, size(X, 2)), '\n'];
fprintf(data_fmt, X')
```

Here `X` denotes the matrix that you want to print (don't forget to transpose `X` in the last line!).
Sample output for `col_w = 10` and `fr_n = 4`:

```
Iteration:
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
|    0     |    1     |    2     |    3     |    4     |    5     |    6     |    7     |    8     
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
|   0.0000 |   3.4000 |  -0.0556 |   1.3848 |   1.0250 |   0.9300 |   1.0558 |   0.9813 |   1.0034 
|   0.0000 |   4.0000 |   0.8603 |   2.1810 |   2.0329 |   1.9030 |   2.0453 |   1.9826 |   1.9997 
|   0.0000 |   2.5000 |   4.5444 |   2.1023 |   3.3195 |   2.9782 |   2.9513 |   3.0402 |   2.9831 
|   0.0000 |   2.0000 |   5.3463 |   3.5175 |   4.0772 |   4.0612 |   3.9463 |   4.0266 |   3.9939 
|   0.0000 |   6.7778 |   3.8111 |   5.4106 |   4.9648 |   4.9366 |   5.0513 |   4.9777 |   5.0046
```

Comment: % #Print header <br/>
hdr_line = repmat(['+', char('-' * ones(1, 10))], 1, size(X, 2));<br/>
fprintf('Iteration:\n%s\n', hdr_line)<br/>
fprintf('|%5.0f     ', 0:size(X, 2) - 1)<br/>
fprintf('\n%s\n', hdr_line)<br/>

% # Print values<br/>
fprintf([repmat('|%9.4f ', 1, size(X, 2)), '\n'], X')<br/>

Wow man that's awesome!<br/>

I added that command at the end of my program, but the numbers are not aligned and it doesn't continue down the display when the iteration's too long in a row.<br/>

I tried to put my codes here, but it's not well displayed.<br/>

I'm really grateful! :)

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, the alignment problem starts when the numbers inside the table exceed 5 digits including the decimals.

Comment: @Wal This means that you need to fiddle a little with the formatting values. I've updated my answer to be configurable, so just change the table properties `col_w` and `fr_n` to your liking.

Comment: Thanks a lot, EitanT! I could have never thought of using the codes that way. I've been thinking of loops all this while! >.< Thanks! :D

Comment: @Wal You _can_ implement it with loops, but sometimes MATLAB allows you to manage without them (there are certainly built-in loops under the hood, but these are not the ones I'm talking about).

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that the command window is not really designed to give customized output. If you want to display a table with a number above each column the variable viewer (opened by double clicking a variable in the workspace) can do the trick.

However, if you want to print results while the calculation is still active you can look into one of these: [Printing a formatted Table](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33815-printing-a-formatted-table/). The answer is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1892).

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try look into it.Yeah, I want it to print out the results with the fancy column lines.

But the first link has the column fixed. I wonder how we get it to print out in loops like C++ to be displayed in the command window as answer.