# Is there a compact view for matrices in matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

I want to have a look at a large matrix in MATLAB such that all columns are printed in one single line rather than spread out over several lines.

Is such thing possible? That would be great to know.

Comment: related question: [MATLAB: Printing a formatted table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019097/matlab-printing-a-formatted-table)

Comment: Would the `'` be the answer?

Comment: @Magla That would in general not be the answer (Unless it is just a vector, see the answer by Engineero). For viewing a matrix you may also be interested in writing it to a standard format like csv and opening that with Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `disp(matrixName(:))`. The `matrixName(:)` command turns your matrix into a long vector in column-major order, so it basically just shows you the first column, followed by the second, the third, etc.

If that does not do the trick, you could look into the [`doprint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/doprint.html) command.

**EDIT:** You could also save the matrix to a text file and view the file. You do this like so:

```
fileID = fopen('C:/path/to/file/myMatrix.txt');
fprintf(fileID, formatString, myMat);
fclose(fileID);
```

- [`fopen` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html)
- [`fprintf` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)
- Additional information can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html#br5_kad-1)

The `formatString` variable in the above tells `fprintf` how the data should be displayed. If you have a really big matrix with tons of columns, where all of the values are floats, the easiest way to create this string is to use something like:

```
formatString = strcat(repmat('%f ', 1, size(myMat, 2)), '\n');
```

This will create a long string specifying that each element in your matrix is a float, and where it goes, and then cap it off with a line feed so that the next row of your matrix starts on the next line.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. But I actually wanted to have all columns in a single horizontel line rather then in a single vertical line. Is this also possible?

Comment: If the matrix is very large I do not think there is any way to suppress the screen wrap that MATLAB automatically does from within MATLAB. You could save the matrix to a file and then view the file. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Adam I have updated my answer for saving to a file. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress your original matrix with a semicolon and then use the "disp" command to show your matrix however you want.

```
for i = 1 : length(matrix(1,:))
    disp(matrix(:,i))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some "obvious" answers:

1. You can choose a smaller font - then more values will fit in a line
2. You can play with the `format` command to have less digits displayed
3. (my favourite) Use the variable viewer - via "open selection" or Ctrl-D when the name of a variable is highlighted. This will show your matrix in an excel-like table.